# Поиск минимального количества повторов чисел

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, числа, повторы

У меня есть код по поиску просто количества одинаковых чисел в активных текстбоксах по нажатию кнопки и вывод этого количества в `label2`:
C#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Enabled == true))
        {
            label2.Text = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().SelectMany(x => x.Text.Split(" ;:,.-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).GroupBy(x => x).Count(x => x.Count() > 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Подскажите, как мне переделать этот код, чтобы он сравнивал не все активные текстбоксы сразу, а каждый с другим, например, первый со вторым, первый с третьим и т. д., затем возвращался ко второму и сравнивал его со следующими, ну и так далее. Это первое. Второе - нужно, чтобы код после сравнения текстбоксов друг с другом вывел в текст лэйбла (можно хоть куда) минимальное количество одинаковых чисел, можно даже `0`, то есть даже если совпадений вообще нет. И хотелось бы, чтобы после всего этого всё-таки как-то выявить в каких текстбоксах было найдено минимум повторяющихся чисел, например, поменять их фоновые цвета (`BackColor`) на другие.

Небольшое пояснение ко всему этому.
В коде `tb` - это массив нескольких текстбоксов.
В каждом тектбоксе все числа разные и не повторяются, они вводятся пользователем, а не рандомно, и через пробел.
И для понятности приведу простой пример с тремя текстбоксами. В первом есть числа `10 15 20`, во-втором `10 11 25`, в третьем `30 11 25`. 
Здесь видно, что у первого со вторым одно совпадение, у второго с третьим два, у первого с третьим ни одного. В итоге мин. кол-во одинаковых чисел - `0`, и это число вставляется в текст лэйбла, а текстбоксы первый и третий меняют свой цвет фона.

Да, и ещё, если будет не трудно, как мне сделать, чтобы по нажатию уже другой кнопки сравнивать текстбоксы не каждый с каждым, а только первый со всеми остальными? Например, если текстбокса 3, то сравнить первый со вторым и с третьим, а уже второй с третьим не надо. Ну и опять же после всего этого вывести минимум и поменять цвет фонов.
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Сфррмулируйте краткое и минимально понятное условие, например `посчитать количество чисел, присутсующих во всех массивах сразу`.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример на массивах целых чисел. Как их получить и строки `TextBox.Text` у вас в коде уже есть пример.

Допустим имеем список массивов `List<int[]> arrays;`

> Подскажите, как мне переделать этот код, чтобы он сравнивал не все
>   активные текстбоксы сразу, а каждый с другим, например, первый со
>   вторым, первый с третьим и т. д., затем возвращался ко второму и
>   сравнивал его со следующими, ну и так далее.

простой переборный алгоритм поиска.

```
var min = a.Max(p => p.Length) + 1;
var index1 = -1;
var index2 = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < arrays.Count - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < arrays.Count; j++)
    {
        var t = arrays[i].Intersect(arrays[j]);
        if(min > t)
        {
            min = t;
            index1 = i;
            index2 = j;
        }
    }
```

на выходе получаем минимум из возможных пересечений и два индекса массивов, дающих это минимальное пересечение. Сложность порядка O(N^3) с учетом поиска пересечений.

> как мне сделать, чтобы по нажатию уже другой кнопки сравнивать
>   текстбоксы не каждый с каждым, а только первый со всеми остальными?

точно также, только вместо внешнего цикла, в котором меняется `i` - фиксируете ее значение на нужном индексе и начинаете с `j = 0`. Сложность порядка O(N^2) с учетом поиска пересечений.

> нужно, чтобы код после сравнения текстбоксов друг с другом вывел в
>   текст лэйбла (можно хоть куда) минимальное количество одинаковых
>   чисел, можно даже 0, то есть даже если совпадений вообще нет. И
>   хотелось бы, чтобы после всего этого всё-таки как-то выявить в каких
>   текстбоксах было найдено минимум повторяющихся чисел, например,
>   поменять их фоновые цвета (BackColor) на другие.

Теперь вы знаете и значение минимума, которое осталось просто вписать в нужный `Label`, и индексы массивов образующих нужную пару.
Если индексы массивов соответствуют индексам `TextBox`-ов, это не сложно обеспечить используя цикл из вашего примера, то мы знаем и индексы `TextBox`-ов которые нужно перекрасить.